# Facebook app not resulting the photos

Tags: facebook

I have created an Facebook APP for fetching user photos and integrated on my website. When I try to get the photos, system asks me for login authentication. That works fine but I am not getting user photos. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

I have set the permission for user_photos. Please refer screenshot @ https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SDxwUWfWSIym4CdtPTF_c1vRzjpenYea/view. We have checked our coding flow. It seems everything is fine from our end. You can reproduce the issue at my store http://standalone.brushyourideas.com/index.php/productdesigner/index/index/id/1070/templateid/MjY0/. Please refer video to follow the steps for reproducing the issue @ https://share.vidyard.com/watch/Vj8WxLQ1GBwC1ibAc1V4Ts

Comment: does it work for your own account? do you get asked for the user_photos permission in the login process? in the video, you are already authorized but we do not know if you are authorized with the user_photos permission.

Comment: No, it doesn't work for my own account also. I have already set the user_photos permission. You can refer the screenshot shared as above.

Comment: that screenshot only shows that it is "approved" (by facebook, so you can use it for every user), but not if it is "authorized". make sure you understand the difference. you do have to ask for the permission in the login process.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Can you please let me know how can i get this or from where?

Comment: you just ask for the user_photos permission in the login process. there is really nothing else to say, to be honest. just use the scope parameter.